# Graph API - Is there a way to search for a user that has a mobile phone number set as his 2FA method?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

So, I'd like to search for a user that has particular number set as his 2FA mobile phone?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely not possible by one call. It requires more steps. The limitation is that you can't expand authentication relationship on user resource, so this query will not work

```
GET /v1.0/users?$expand=authentication/phoneMethods
```

You can use the [report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authenticationmethodsroot-list-userregistrationdetails?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) (requires `AuditLog.Read.All` permission) with a list of the authentication methods registered for users and filter users by registered methods

```
GET /v1.0/reports/authenticationMethods/userRegistrationDetails?$filter=methodsRegistered/any(x:x eq 'mobilePhone')&$select=id,methodsRegistered
```

Then iterate all users with phone method

```
GET /v1.0/users/{user_id}/authentication/phoneMethods
```

and check if the user has the phone number you are looking for.